# Fix BOOTMGR from Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.10, windows

I installed Ubuntu 12.10 on my computer and decided to go to Windows XP. I inserted the reinstall CD and it just says:

> BOOTMGR Missing, click <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd> to restart.

The same thing happens with Windows 7. I'm assuming that the `BOOTMGR` needs to be restored/repaired but I don't know how to do that in Ubuntu. I've read many articles that say to insert the install CD and use the command prompt but seeing as I can't even load the CD that is a problem. So basically my question is, how do I replace/reinstall the `BOOTMGR` through Ubuntu?

Comment: Some clarifications need here. Can you boot into Ubuntu now ? Have you used the same windows CD for installing in your system or somewhere before ? As i remember "bootmgr missing" error is because of the improper boot priority of the device. If you set proper boot device you can boot into your system.

Comment: Yes, I can boot into ubuntu. I have used the same windows CD before on this computer. And it's not that I can't boot into windows, it's that I can't install it.
@learner

Comment: This is a question about installing Windows, not Ubuntu. I'm flagging this for migration on SuperUser.

Comment: If you're trying to get Ubuntu and Windows to both be bootable, I think the solutions at [How can I repair grub? ...](http://askubuntu.com/q/88384) may help (even if Ubuntu boots now). Unless you installed Ubuntu with Wubi--then please edit your question with more details about how you installed Ubuntu. If you want to *just* get Windows working (removing Ubuntu), see [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](http://askubuntu.com/q/133533). The parts there that explain how to put the Windows boot loader back may fix this too (do that so Windows boots, then repair GRUB so both will boot).

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you checked the boot priority on your Bios? Re-check if your CD drive is first on your boot.
2. If you somehow manage to get to the Windows 7 repair console type in the following commands:

   ```
   bootrec.exe /FixMBR
   bootrec.exe /FixBoot
   ```
3. If you can boot your Ubuntu dist, you can try using a partitioning software (like disk utility), select the partition where you installed it (probably labeled System), right click the partition and mark it as boot.

Comment: 1. The CD drive is first.
2. That's what I would do /if/ I could get into the Windows 7 repair console.
3. Installed what? Windows? Because windows isn't installed. Only Ubuntu.